# Comparing two dataframes in ddply function

Tags: r, plyr

I've two dataframes, `Data` and `quantiles`. `Data` has a dimension of `23011 x 2` and consists of columns `"year"` and `"data"` where year are the sequence of days from 1951:2013. The `Quantiles` df has a dimension of `63x2` consists of columns `"year"` and `"quantiles"` , where year are 63 rows, ie. `1951:2013`.

I need to compare `Quantile` df against the `Data` df and count the sum of data values exceeding the quantiles value for each year. For that, I'm using `ddply` in this manner :

```
ddply(data, .(year), function(y) sum(y[which(y[,2] > quantile[,2]),2]) )
```

However, the code compares only against the first row of quantile and is not iterating over each of the year against the data df.
I want to iterate over each year in `quantile` df and calculate the sum of data exceeding the `quantile` df in each year.

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

The example problem - 
`quantile` df is [here](http://ur1.ca/ntya2)
and `Data` is [pasted here](http://fpaste.org/269604/42824692/)

The `quantile` df is derived from the `data` , which is the 90th percentile `data` df exceeding value 1

```
quantile = quantile(data[-c(which(prcp2[,2] < 1)),x],0.9)})
```

Comment: Hi, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And is the 'quantiles'-data derived from the original data, or from an external source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the Heroka answer above, If you have 10,000 columns and need to iterate over each of the column, you can use matrix notation in this form -

```
lapply(x, function(y) {ddply(data,.(year), function(x){  return(sum(x[x[,y] > quantile(x[x[,y]>1,y],0.9),y]))})})
```

where `x` is the size of columns, ie, `1:1000` and `data` is the df which contains the data. 
The `quantile(x[x[,y]>1,y],0.9),y])` will give the 90th percentile for data values exceeding `1` . 
`x[x[,y] > quantile(x[x[,y]>1,y],0.9),y]` returns the rows which satisfies the condition for the `yth` column and `sum` function is used to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this in one go? Creating the `quantiles`-dataframe first and then referring back to it makes things more complicated than they need to be. You can do this with ddply too.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  year=sample(1951:2013,23011,replace=T),
  data=rnorm(23011)
)


res <- ddply(data,.(year), function(x){
  return(sum(x$data[x$data>quantile(x$data,.9)]))
})
```

And -as plyr seems to be replaced with dplyr - :

```
library(dplyr)


res2 <- mydf %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(
  test=sum(value[value>quantile(value,.9)])
)
```

Comment: Thanks Heroka for the answer. It worked . However you missed one condition where `quantile` df should be greater than 1. Though, I put the condition and it gave the expected answer. The detailed answer will be posted to help other guys. Thanks again.